# Can I combine two html buttons and their onclick methods using something like javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html> 
    <div class="button">
         <input type="button" onclick="method1();" id="1" value="Button1"/>
    </div>

     <div class="button">
         <input type="button" onclick="method2();" id="2" value="Button2"/>
     </div>
</html>
```

Without having to modify the Html, can I combine the two buttons into one button? And when that button is clicked, can both the methods be called? Can this be done with Javascript/JQuery? If so, how would you do it?

In other words, can I hide one button and fire both methods without changing the html.

Comment: Define what you mean by "combine the two buttons into one button" - do you mean just hide one button and fire both click events when the remaining button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#1, #2").click(function(){
   method1();
   method2();
   return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on Yardboy's comment the OP might want this instead

```
$(function(){
  $("#2").parent().hide();
  $("#1").click(function(){
     method1();
     method2();
     return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: This would mean that one of the methods would get called twice right, if the html is not changed?

Comment: throw in a `return false;` and it will only do each function once.  Or an `event.preventDefault()`, though that requires you to pass in the event object.

Comment: You are right. Using `unbind()` will help with that though. Thanks!

Comment: @Surreal's suggestion is better than mine calling unbind at every click!

Comment: Thanks so much, this stuff is new to me.

Comment: @Rolando - based on OP response to my query above, you should bind the method1() and method2() calls to the click of the first button only, and add a line to hide the parent of the second button. I don't want to scoop your answer, since you're mostly there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add both method calls to one onclick attribute.

```
<div class="button">
     <input type="button" onclick="method1();method2();" id="1" value="Button1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: "Without having to modify the Html"